# R: Gmisc / Grid and alignment of boxes

Tags: r, grid, gmisc

I would like to create a dynamic flow-chart using "Gmisc", "grid", and lists in R.

Basically the code looks as follows:

```
##############################

library(Gmisc)
library(grid)

# list of names
a.names <- list("i1", "i2", "i3")

# list of boxes
a <- list(boxGrob("item 1"), 
          boxGrob("item 2"), 
          boxGrob("item 3")
)
# asigning names to list
names(a) <- a.names

# spreading boxes
b <- spreadHorizontal(a)
names(b) <- (a.names)

# clear view
grid.newpage()

# print boxes spread horizontal
b
```

Now, a second list of boxes should be aligned vertically along the first box (Item 1).

using

```
alignHorizontal(reference = b$i1, a) %>% spreadVertical(.from = 0.9, .to=0.6)
```

results in an error, while

```
dummy <- b$i2
temp <- alignHorizontal(reference = dummy, a$i1, a$i2) 
spreadVertical(temp, .from=0.9, .to=0.6)
```

works fine, and

```
dummy <- b$i3
temp <- alignHorizontal(reference = dummy, a) 
spreadVertical(temp, .from=0.9, .to=0.6)
```

results in an error.
Obviously, the `alignHorizontal` needs single elements and cannot deal with a list of elements.
Is there any chance to hand over a list of boxes to that function?

Sincerely,
Steffen

Answer (score 0):

One option to pass your list would be to use `do.call` like so:

```r
library(Gmisc)
#> Loading required package: Rcpp
#> Loading required package: htmlTable
library(grid)

# list of names
a.names <- list("i1", "i2", "i3")

# list of boxes
a <- list(
  boxGrob("item 1"),
  boxGrob("item 2"),
  boxGrob("item 3")
)
# asigning names to list
names(a) <- a.names

# spreading boxes
b <- spreadHorizontal(a)
names(b) <- (a.names)

# clear view
grid.newpage()

# print boxes spread horizontal
b

do.call(alignHorizontal, c(list(reference = b$i1), a)) |>
  spreadVertical(.from = 0.9, .to = 0.6)
```

[image]